# Is there a way to get API's from AWS API Gateway by name instead of ID using the AWS CLI?

Tags: api, aws-api-gateway, aws-cli

`aws apigateway get-rest-api --rest-api-id <api_id>`   --> gives you a specific API but I want to know is there a way that u can get an API by its name using the `aws` cli.

I have already tried this command but didn't work.

```
aws apigateway get-rest-api --rest-api-name <api_name>
```

Comment: This post can be of interest: https://viesure.io/automating-aws-using-cli-output/

Answer (score 7):

You can use some like this:

```
aws apigateway get-rest-apis --query 'items[?name==`APIGATEWAYNAME`]'
```

But it will return a list instead of a single element.

Comment: hi thank you. Can you explain this to me with an example?

Comment: To return the first element of the list: `aws apigateway get-rest-apis --query "items[?name=='APIGATEWAYNAME'] | [0]"`

Answer (score 3):

You can further extract ID using Json Parser utility, jq (in Linux / MAC)

```
api_id_extracted=$(aws apigateway get-rest-apis --query 'items[?name==`APIGATEWAYNAME`]' --output json | jq '.[0] .id')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want just the ID you can use:

```
aws apigateway get-rest-apis --query 'items[?name==`APIGATEWAYNAME`].[id]' --output text
```

Where `APIGATEWAYNAME` is the name of your API Gateway.